# Spring configuration problem after Spring AOP implementation

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm trying to implement Spring AOP in multiple layers application and make advice for @Service and @Controller classes.

Everything works fine without aspect class. When I add that part of code it causes Spring configuration problem.

@Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ApplicationMonitor {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationMonitor.class);

@Pointcut(value = "execution(* hr.mycompany.controller.impl.MyCompanyController.update(*)) && args(obj)") 
public void updateMC(Object obj){}

@Before(value="updateMC(obj)")
public void beforeUpdateMC(JoinPoint jp, Object obj) {
    Object obj = jp.getArgs()[0];
    logger.info("beforeUpdateMC " + obj);
}
```

}

Spring XML aspect configuration:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Application @Controller and @Service classes:

```
@Controller 
public class MyCompanyController implements IMyCompanyController{

    @Autowired
    private IMyComapnyService myCompanyService;

}


@Service
public class MyCompanyService implements IMyComapnyService {

    @Autowired
    private IGenericHibernateDao<Object, Integer>  vwObjectDao;

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


09:11:27,871 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/BasicData-portlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8083-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyCompanyService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao hr.mycompany.services.impl.MyCompanyService.vwObjectDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Where the problem is?

EDIT:

Part of class with Hibernate methods:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public abstract class GenericHibernateDao<T, PK extends Serializable> implements IGenericHibernateDao<T, PK> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericHibernateDao.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "hibernateSessionFactory")
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public PK save(T entity) {
        Assert.notNull(entity, "Argument entity cannot be null in a call to GenericHibernateDao.save !");

        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        return (PK) session.save(entity);
    }

    ...

}
```

EDIT (22-02-2019):

When I change this line of code:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

like this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Error disapears, but aspect does not work.

Comment: You have `hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao` and one implementation for it? Can you show the essential parts of those?

Comment: @pirho Implementation contatins hibernate methods. I'm confused about error because everything is ok without aspect implementation.

Comment: Please edit these into your question and delete the comments.

Comment: I think I already told you how to fix your aspect code in the other question, so maybe it would make sense to copy the working aspect into this follow-up question instead of the broken one so everyone can concentrate on your new problem. Or are you maybe still using an aspect with invalid syntax? Show us exactly what you have if you believe the aspect causes the problem.

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry, it's my mistake - I copy-pasted aspect from previous question - but aspect is now correct - I changed them exactly like you corrected me. I will now edit aspect part of code in my question.

Comment: Is it so difficult to copy my aspect code? You still get the method parameter via `getArgs()[0]` even though it is already bound to the method parameter via `args(obj)`. Sorry to speak so frankly, but sloppy questions yield sloppy answers. You do want help though, don't you?

Comment: I told you in previous question that your solution does not work in my app. When I change code like you told me in my previous question I'm getting error org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. When I delete aspect code everything works fine. So I'm very confused about where the problem is.

Comment: @kriegaex I edited this question - do you know why I have that problem? I think it is related to aspect code.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. Even though you share lots of information, it is just a set incomplete code and config snippets. I am repeating myself for the 5th time or so within these two questions of yours, so one last time: Please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem. Ideally publish it on GitHub incl. a Maven POM so everyone can build and run your sample code. And also one last time: The aspect is not the problem. That the fixed aspect kicks in just reveals a configuration problem elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you for your answer. I'm not allowed to publish code to GitHub because of company I work for. You think something from the beginning is not well set up in the Spring configuration?

Comment: Lame excuse. An MCVE is not your company's code but something similar, a minimal example demonstrating your problem. Did you even read the article I pointed you to? Go help yourself then, good luck. It is way too tedious to kind of persuade you to let me help you by sharing minimal information, no company secrets. Sorry to be so blunt, but after our discussions here and in the other question both my patience and your new user bonus have expired.

Comment: I did MCVE. I told you for pushing code to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

I change this line of code in Spring XML config file:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

I set proxy-target-class to false:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
```

I deleted this dependency from pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I set the same spring-aop vesion like Spring version I use in Spring XML config file.

I changed this:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
```

like this:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
```